# Should UnitOfWork implement IDisposable in EF Core？

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I have read a Q&A written 9 years ago, here is the link: [entity framework - Unit of Work, Repositories and IDisposable - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15972978/unit-of-work-repositories-and-idisposable#:%7E:text=Yes%2C)

which showed it should implement `IDisposable`. But other videos posted on YouTube don't. Should it implement `IDisposable` interface now?

How can it roll back when there is no transaction that the entities have a foreign key association?

```
public class Employee
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public long DepartmentId { get; set; }
}

public class Department
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public void AddDepartmentAndEmployees()
{
    var department = new Department { Name = "Dev" };

    var employees = new List<Employee> 
    { 
       new Employee { Name = "Jack" },
       new Employee { Name = "Tim" },
    }

    _departmentRepository.Add(department);
    _departmentRepository.SaveChange();

    employees.All(e => e.DepartmentId = department.Id );
    // if there throw a unknown exception
    // and how can i roll back?
    _employeeRespository.AddRange(employees);
    _departmentRepository.SaveChange();
}
```

Solve the above two problems.

Sorry about my poor English, but I have try my best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this may help you [Transactions in unit of work design pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34609038/transactions-in-unit-of-work-design-pattern)

It's a best practice to have the UnitOfWork being disposable according to Microsoft [article about UnitOfWork Design Pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application)

you can use TransactionScope to create transactions and commit or roll it back if you have any problem

Comment: You solved a problem that has been plaguing me for a long time! @Montero_Dev

Comment: Is there another way to guarantee transactions using repository mode？@Montero_Dev